# Commands from within python script not found

Tags: python, command, subprocess, call

I am working with the [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) commandline tool to convert a file inside a python script. I am able to convert the file manually from a command prompt window, but when I execute my code form the same working directory I am returned with an error:

`'sox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

sox is my path. But not being found. Is it possible when python running the subprocess.call method the current working directory is changed for that method, and is run in a location where some of my path variables are not being found?

This is how I am running my code that does not find "sox"

```
    print("Enter a name for the .wav output file")
    filename = raw_input()
    + " " + filename + ".wav"
    COMMAND = "sox " + fileOut + " " + filename + ".wav"
    subprocess.call(COMMAND, shell = True)
```

If i make my command this it executes correctly...

```
COMMAND = "C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe " + fileOut + " " + filename + ".wav"
```

Why is sox not being found from within this python file?

Comment: but is your directory in your path? the command which works uses full path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop your `shell=True` and make `COMMAND` a list:

```
COMMAND = ["sox", fileOut, filename + ".wav"]
subprocess.call(COMMAND)
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why this would fix the problem, but it did!